# `` Template Syntax - Graceful Degredation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The new javascript template syntax is great. Super readable and powerful. I'd like to start using it.

I tried this template:

```
function addGalleryItem(imageData, file) { 
    try {
        var template = `
            <section class="imageGalleryItem">
                <img src="${imageData}"/>
                <div class="itemTools" id="${file.name}">
                    <input type="text" class="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"/> <br />
                    <input type="button" name="mainImage" value="Main Image" onclick="makeMain(this)"/>
                    <input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeImage(this)"/>
                </div>
            </section>
        `;
    } catch { 
        var template = '<section class="imageGalleryItem">' +
            '   <img src="' + imageData + '" />' +
            '   <div class="itemTools" id="' + file.name + '">' +
            '       <input type="text" class="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"/>'+
            '       <br />' +
            '       <input type="button" name="mainImage" value="Main Image" onclick="makeMain(this)"/>' +
            '       <input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeImage(this)"/>' +
            '   </div>' +
            '</section> ';
    }

    $('#imageGallery').append(template);

}
```

But dear IE squawks about a syntax error because of the backticks (`). [MSDN's article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858580(v=vs.94).aspx) totes the awesomeness of Edge and doesn't mention what to do for IE.

Is there a way to use the new template syntax directly for production use today? Or are we stuck transpiling?

Comment: You can't catch syntax errors with try...catch -.-

Comment: @Gothdo Yes, I am aware. It's customary to show what we've tried though and I couldn't think of anything else to try.

Comment: How could you use a feature a browser doesn't support without an intermediate step?

Comment: Stuff like this is exactly the problem Babel solves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use try...catch statement to catch syntax errors, because they are thrown even before the code is executed.

You either have to drop support for browsers which doesn't support template literals or use Babel.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can use `eval` to assert if the browser supports certain syntax changes:

```
var isTemplateSupported = true;
try {
    eval("``");
}
catch(e) {
    isTemplateSupported = false;
}
console.log("Supports Template Literals", isTemplateSupported);
```

So for your implementation:

```
var template;
try {
    template = eval("`<section class=\"imageGalleryItem\">`".....);
}
catch(e) {
    if(e instanceof SyntaxError) {
        template = '<section class="imageGalleryItem">' + ...
    }
}
```

But it's much easier to use a transpiler because it would be tedious to support two implementations *every* time you need a literal.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, and I agree, it is cumbersome. But at least something exists.